# PyQt5 distinguish ok and cancel command

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

This is dialog code using PyQt5 QDialog.

```
class QDialogUI(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()

        self.okButton = QPushButton("Ok", self)
        self.okButton.clicked.connect(self.acceptCommand)
        self.okButton.clicked.connect(lambda:self.closeCommand(1))

        self.cancelButton = QPushButton("Cancel", self)
        self.cancelButton.clicked.connect(lambda:self.closeCommand(0))

    def acceptCommand(self):
        ...
        return date, asset, sort, money, text

    def closeCommand(self, status):
        return status
```

And this is main code.

```
def openDialog(self):
    self.dlg = QDialogUI()
    self.dlg.exec_()
    if self.dlg.closeCommand() == 1:
        iD = list(self.dlg.acceptCommand())
        self.params.emit(iD[0],iD[1],iD[2],iD[3],iD[4])
```

If I clicked okButton or cancelButton, Both of them don't react. And I close QDialogUI, it shows error like:

```
TypeError: closeCommand()missing 1 required positional argument: 'status'
```

How can I get 'return of acceptCommand' when 'okButton.clicked'?
Or is there more better code that distinguish ok and cancel command?

Comment: Typo: change `self.okButton.clicked.connect(lambda:closeCommand(0))` to `self.okButton.clicked.connect(lambda:self.closeCommand(0))`

Comment: That was my mistake..sorry...

Comment: another typo: add `super().__init__()` before `self.okButton = QPushButton("Ok", self)`

Comment: It also in my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to create an attribute of the class that saves that information when it is pressed and that can be used later:

```
class QDialogUI(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.status = None
        self.okButton = QPushButton("Ok", self)
        self.okButton.clicked.connect(self.acceptCommand)
        self.okButton.clicked.connect(lambda:self.closeCommand(1))

        self.cancelButton = QPushButton("Cancel", self)
        self.cancelButton.clicked.connect(lambda:self.closeCommand(0))

    def acceptCommand(self):
        ...
        self.status = date, asset, sort, money, text

    def closeCommand(self, status):
        return self.status
```

Comment: Yeah! It worked. I couldn't think of it. Thank you for answer